# Why can't I access Session values from Page_Init that were stored during a previous postback?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I'm storing Session values inside of Page_Load during postback, but I'm unable to access them in Page_Init on the next round trip. The gist of my logic is that the end user should be able to log in on postback during Page_Load where values are stored in the Session object, then on the next round trip I can grab those values from the Session object and initialize objects of a custom type. Initially I attempted to initialize my objects based on the values stored in the Session, but when I found that wasn't working I added some code in Page_Init to debug and found that I wasn't able to access them at all. The catch is that I'm able to access the values fine if I completely reload the page - but if I try to refresh or try to fire the postback button again it's as though the code is ignored.

I'm able to access other values in the Session with this logic (I have a "StartTime" value I'm able to get that's created in BeginRequest) but I'm not able to access the ones created during postback in Page_Load.

This is independent of my custom type as I've tried with hardcoded values and arrived at the same result.

Where my postback is handled:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Select Case Me.form_action.Value.ToLower()
        Case "save"
            If Me.tab.ActiveTabIndex = 0 Then
                cart.Login(Me.login.Value, Me.password.Value)
                UpdateRecord()
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

These methods update the database and store the session value:

```
Public Sub UpdateRecord()
    cart.UpdateDB()
    SaveCart()
End Sub
Public Sub SaveCart()
    If Not cart.ID > 0 Then Exit Sub
    Me.cart_id.Value = cart.ID
    Session("seminars_cart_id") = cart.ID
End Sub
```

This is where I attempt to access the data in Page_Init

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Session.Keys.Count > 0 Then
        phDbg.InnerHtml = ""
        For Each k As Object In Session.Keys
            Me.phDbg.InnerHtml += String.Format("Session({0}) - {1}<br />", k, Session(k))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```